# Items missing workflow audit report

Tags: content-editor, publishing

I'm working on a rescue project and have started to noticed that there are quite a number of items not associated with a workflow. A few of the content editors have reported that sometimes items can be published straight to production but not all.

How can I audit the solution to see what is not associated?

Comment: Are you allowed to install third-party modules into your instance ?

Comment: Yes we can. Turns out we already had SPE installed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with Sitecore Powershell Extensions, just use the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse |? { $_.__Workflow -eq "" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **Advanced System Reporter** sitecore marketplace module.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/A/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx